# How to solve the error in WPF component on c# windows forms project?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I have created the Windows C# project.There is one windows form. In the same project I created a WPF component and when i try to place this component on windows form some error is coming "Failed to create component".

Please check the link below to get more details about error.

1.When I drag the component from toolbox to form this error comes:
[image]

2.while i select the WPF component in ElementHost I get this error:
[image]

Please help me this.

Comment: Please add some relevant code related to error so that anyone can analyze your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your component Grid_Buttons does not have a default constructor with no parameters which is required by the designer to automatically generate code.