# C# elementhost error inserting wpf usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I appreciate any ideas to solve those errors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565125/how-to-solve-the-error-in-wpf-component-on-c-sharp-windows-forms-project#new-answer?newreg=9740e8aff057412ba206aec2691d429b).

basicaly in an elementhost im trying to insert a WPF layer (simpl usercontrol with grid) with inside of it an usercontrol (a numericUpDown). Knowing that my wpf application compiles with no errors!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.